# Seeking historical (pre-war) data on cities and towns in Germany?

Tags: data, demography, germany

I'm trying to find and merge German city-level data from various time periods: ~1900, ~1930 and ~1990.

**What's difficult**:

Obviously some cities merged, new places were founded after 1900, and again others are in nowadays Poland or France. I am mainly interested in finding data on population densities and further demographics, but would need to know in detail whether some data point pertains to exactly the same unit of observations.

Example: Older data might have an entry for "Ebingen" in Baden-Württemberg. In 1975 Albstadt was founded and Ebingen became a part of Albstadt so more recent data will have Albstadt not Ebingen, but Albstadt also contains other places.

**What I need**:

Is there any public dataset available that

- provides information on such changes,
- provides pre-war demographics (population etc.), and ideally
- links pre-war town names to today's municipality-IDs (GKZ)?

Answer (score 2):

Look for [INSPIRE](http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/). INSPIRE is a European initiative that nudges member countries to make geographically oriented data available for all, for free.

In the Netherlands this has resulted in -among others- a site [PDOK](http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/) that offers map-layers of all kind. Many of the layers are instantiated from databases and can be queried. Many of these layers have a temporal dimension. One of the layers (in the Netherlands) shows administrative boundaries.

I believe that in Germany [Geoportal](http://www.geoportal.de/DE/Geoportal/Karten/Themenkarten/themenkarten.html) is one of the providers of INSPIRE data. My knowledge of the German language is insufficient to determine if the exact layers (and temporal extent) you need are available.